# codeigniter 3.1 upgradation showing error The configuration file url.php does not exist

Tags: php, codeigniter

codeigniter 3.1 upgradation showing error The configuration file url.php does not exist.While the log file doesn't showing exact error. Here is the log details

[image]

```
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> CSRF cookie sent
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Language Class Initialized
INFO - 2017-05-14 22:11:57 --> Loader Class Initialized
```

Comment: CodeIgniter doesn't have or need such a config file; one of your libraries/extensions is triggering the error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `config/autoload.php`

enter this code in the helper section

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form');
```